# Wordpress вывод категорий

Tags: php, wordpress

Редактирую шаблон на WP. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не полностью выводятся посты из категории портфолио.

```
  <?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++; global $post; $taxo = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfoliocat');?>

                <!-- gallery item -->

                <li data-type="<?php foreach ($taxo as $taxx) { echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $taxx->slug)). ' '; } ?>" data-id="id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="view <?php foreach ($taxo as $taxx) { echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $taxx->slug)). ' '; } ?>">
                             <?php echo "count = $count"; ?>
                    <?php
                        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'portfolio-bits','portfolio-bits' );
                        $large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large', false);
                        if(has_post_thumbnail()): echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'"/>'; else: ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/gallery_sample.jpg" alt="portfolio" />

                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <a class="info" href="<?php echo $large[0] ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><?php _e('+','site5framework') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <!-- end gallery item -->

            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

А именно, выводятся только 9 постов. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1) В админки есть настройки сколько постов выводить

Comment: 2) сделайте параметр 'posts_per_page' => -1 в запросе

Comment: У Вас скорее всего берется указаное количество постов на страницу в `Настройки->Чтение`. Для вывода другого количества постов, передайте параметр перед циклом `posts_per_page` с нужным количеством.

Comment: posts_per_page(число) Количество постов на одной странице. Если выставить -1, то будут выведены все посты (без пагинации).

Comment: Всем спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) сделайте параметр 'posts_per_page' => -1 в запросе – Даниил